# Query para separar registros

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql

Boa tarde galera, estou com dificuldade em realizar uma query.

Tenha a seguinte tabela

[image: Tabela de Telefones]

Gostaria de fazer uma query que mostre qual e quantos status_telefonia teve por telefone e data, em seguida criar uma tabela com todos telefones que teve mais de 5 OU + status "MACHINE" OU "INVALID NUMBER" sendo que nenhum desses telefones teve  o Status "RANDOM"

Acho um pouco completo mas preciso muito da ajuda de vocês

Comment: Vejo que colocou tag de 3 SGBD, seria em todos mesmo ?

Comment: atualizei, é no postgreSQL.

Answer (score 2):

Para a primeira parte, como você mesmo disse, você quer agrupar e contar os eventos por telefone e data. Para isso utilizaremos a cláusula `GROUP BY` e a função `COUNT`.

---

> **[GROUP BY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY)**
>
> **Original:** GROUP BY will condense into a single row all selected rows that share the same values for the grouped expressions.
>
> **Tradução livre:** GROUP BY irá combinar em uma única linha todos os registros selecionados que compartilhem os mesmos valores nas expressões agrupadas.

---

> **[COUNT](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-count-function/)**
>
> **Original:** The COUNT function returns the number of input rows that match a specific condition of a query.
>
> **Tradução livre:** A função COUNT retorna o número de linhas que coincide com a condição especificada na query.

---

```
SELECT telefone,
       data_registro,
       COUNT(1) as quantidade
  FROM tabela t
 GROUP BY telefone, data_registro;
```

Para a segunda parte continuaremos utilizando a cláusula `GROUP BY` e a função `COUNT`, aliado ao `NOT EXISTS` para verificar se não existe `status_telefonia` `RANDOM` para aquele número e a cláusula `HAVING` para restringir os resultados àqueles que tem 5 ou mais ocorrências.

---

> **HAVING**
>
> **Original:** HAVING eliminates group rows that do not satisfy the condition. HAVING is different from WHERE: WHERE filters individual rows before the application of GROUP BY, while HAVING filters group rows created by GROUP BY.
>
> **Tradução livre:** HAVING elimina um grupo de linhas que não satisfaz a condição. HAVING é diferente de WHERE: WHERE filtra linhas individuais antes da aplicação do GROUP BY, enquanto HAVING filtra grupos de linhas criadas pelo GROUP BY.

---

> **[EXISTS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/functions-subquery.html)**
>
> **Original:** The argument of EXISTS is an arbitrary SELECT statement, or subquery. The subquery is evaluated to determine whether it returns any rows. If it returns at least one row, the result of EXISTS is "true"; if the subquery returns no rows, the result of EXISTS is "false".
>
> **Tradução livre:** O argumento do EXISTS é uma declaração arbitrária do SELECT, ou subquery. A subquery é avaliada para determinar se alguma linha será retornada. Se retornar ao menos uma linha, o resultado do EXISTS é "verdadeiro"; se a subquery não retornar linhas, o resultado do EXISTS é "falso".

---

```
SELECT telefone,
       COUNT(1) as quantidade
  FROM tabela t
 WHERE status_telefonia IN ('MACHINE', 'INVALID NUMBER')
   AND NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                    FROM tabela t2
                   WHERE t2.telefone = t.telefone
                     AND status_telefonia = 'RANDOM')
 GROUP BY telefone
 HAVING count(1) >= 5;
```